# Terminology: Really Delete vs set IsDeleted ("soft delete") flag

Tags: terminology, data

I have a site where a regular user can delete records, where what happens is that an [`IsDeleted`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549839/are-soft-deletes-a-good-idea) flag gets set. On administrative pages, a privileged user can delete records where an actual SQL `DELETE` permanently discards such records. The difference is important for obvious reasons, and I want to use a consistent term to refer to the one form of deletion vs. the other. I've been playing with the words `Remove`, `Delete`, `Discard` and possibly `Recycle`, and `Archive`.

My question is: are there standard user-facing terms that distinguish these two behaviors?

Comment: Just a few examples: In IMAP, the terminology is *delete* (soft delete) vs. *expunge* (hard delete). In Windows, the terminology is *delete* (move to recycle bin) vs. *permanently delete* (remove from recycle bin).

Comment: As long as you don't go down the `delete`, `really_delete`, `really_really_delete` road, you should be fine IMO.

Comment: @HakanDeryal Isn't `really_delete` fairly close to `permanently delete` (from Windows) :-) ?

Comment: Yes, they both sucks.

Comment: How about *delete* vs. *purge*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For regular users they click the `Trash` icon to flag a record for deleting. The privileged users can then view the contents of the `Trash` and delete those icons.

`Delete` is permanent, where as `Trash` can be thought of as a location.

> The user can move records to the Trash.

and

> The privileged user deleted records in the Trash.

The other words don't work well for me.

I don't like `Recycle` because it implies a different meaning then simply deleting records.

`Archive` implies permanent storage, and possibly moving the records to offline storage.

Comment: Your answer has forced me to reconsider my original question. While @Heinzi's comment better answers the question I _thought_ I was asking, you answered the question _I asked_ more precisely than did he. What I am left contemplating is whether there is a difference between a hard and a soft delete if, from the user's standpoint, neither should be recoverable. Or I could just be overthinking the whole matter.

Comment: Well, for me `soft delete` implies a deletion that involves software, and `hard delete` implies a deletion that involves hardware. A `soft delete` of a file would be marking the file as erased in the file system (but the bytes are still there on the hard drive), where as a `hard delete` would be writing zeros to all the bytes on the hard drive to ensure it can not be recovered. For a database a `hard delete` would be compacting the database to ensure the old record can not be recovered by an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

One interface I saw had options to *Retire* (soft-delete) or *Delete* (actually remove) data from the database.

Comment: That UI Designer clearly never saw the movie "Blade Runner", then.

Answer (score 0):

Soft-delete and Hard-delete. I'm sure the difference is obvious enough.

Answer (score -1):

I use:

`Delete` for soft-delete

`Destroy` for remove from database